# Angular 6 working on localhost but not on publishing to server

Tags: angular, browser, styles, publish

I am working on Angular 6, .NET application, which is also using Kendo UI controls from Telerik.
The controls display fine when I run the application on localhost, but after I publish, the Kendo UI controls do not display.
I tried couple of times by doing a prod build, then putting the .NET application in Release mode, build and publish. It had this issue. Then I did dev build using ng build, .NET compile in Debug mode and then published again. But still the same issue. Rest of the features/controls work in Chrome but not kendo ui controls.

After some investigation it seems that styles.css is not loading. It shows published, but when I go to Chrome, dev tools, network tab, I do not see styles.css loaded. Please see img attached. Also I get error in console for vendor.js and styles.js not found (imag attached) - and I see these issues both with prod build and dev build (ng build).[image: styles.css]
[image: vendor and styles js missing]

Comment: Can you go to the server to check the hosting directory to see if `/dist/styles.js` exist?

Comment: Yes, With debug build and publish, I have runtime.js, main.js, polyfills.js, styles.js, vendor.js under dist folder on production. styles.css was not there with dev build but I manually copied since I suspect that is causing the issue.

Comment: For default angular path, you just need to copy the files inside your dist directory (not the dist folder) to server host file. And you may need to rewrite url to point to index.html. Which server you are using nginx or apache? or static host like firebase hosting or s3?

Comment: I meant dist directory.I did not understand what you mean by"you may need to rewrite url to point to index.html"? All I know is that I have specified in Route.config. We are using web server with IIS 7

Comment: Try to read this [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7).... Please check if you are hosting with a `sub-folder` or not. You may have to edit `base-href` like <base href="/dist/"> in html header. Also, since it is SPA, you need to rewrite the route to index.html